# Function works when button clicked but not when submitting the form

Tags: javascript, html

I have yet another question concerning this project but here's hoping ill learn a lot from it.

So I created a function, that creates a div inside a div (which will then contain a random number from dice roll) and it works when I add this function to a button click.

But clicking the button multiple times might not be ideal for a lot of dice, so I created a form and it shouldnt create the number of divs the user decides he wants, but it doesnt seem to work. I suspect it has to do with the form refreshing the page, so instead of handling the even withh addEventListener I used inline "onsumbit" and tried to return the function but it still doesnt seem to work. What am i doing wrong? Here is the HTML and JS bits:

```
    <form>
    <p>Pick how many dice you want to roll:</p>
    <input id="diceNumber" type="number" name="diceNumber" onsubmit="return addMoreDice()">
</form>

<button onclick="addDice()">Add Dice</button>

<div id="diceTable">

</div>
```

and JS:

```
var numInput = document.querySelector("input");

function addDice(){
var div = document.createElement('div');

div.className = "diceStyle";

div.innerHTML = "<p> here will be a dice</p>";

document.getElementById('diceTable').appendChild(div);
};

function addMoreDice(){
for(var i = 0; i < numInput; i++){
    addDice();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the target of submitting form?
`<form action="action"></form>`

Answer (score 0):

1.You should probably include onsubmit() in form tag and add a submit button inside form.

2. You can use onchange() method to invoke  addMoreDice() whenever the value in input box is changed

Answer (score 0):

you need to add onsubmit="yourfunction()" in side form tag
and than put an input type submit inside form tag like

```
    <form action="#" onsubmit="addDice()">
    <p>Pick how many dice you want to roll:</p>
    <input id="diceNumber" type="number" name="diceNumber" onsubmit="return addMoreDice()">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<button onclick="addDice()">Add Dice</button>

<div id="diceTable">

</div>
```

Comment: Still doesnt work, i can see a signle div appearing for a split second before dissapearing, but when I use addMoreDice() i cant see even that

Answer (score 0):

Each time you submit a form, it gets you to a different page. Instead you could have this code as shown below, (remove form tags)

```
<p>Pick how many dice you want to roll:</p>
<input id="diceNumber" type="number" name="diceNumber"></input>
<input type="submit" onClick="addMoreDice()">
```

Clicking on submit after entering the input dynamically creates divisions per your need.

Comment: Then it only works with a mouse click and only on AddDice() function. Perhaps, but i dont know why, my addMoreDice() function doesnt work

Comment: when u click the submit button, it works with the addMoreDice function. Try entering a numeric value in text box and click submit. I tried and it worked